# Why Should I provide an alternative style for 21 api knowing that AppCompat is made for compatibility

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-theme, android-styles

Some material design  are only supported starting from android 21 API  , so for this purpose we need to provide alternative styles that will work on devices running earlier version  . (like they say in documentation ) .

for example  :

```
res/values/styles.xml
res/values-v21/styles.xml
```

They also have mentioned V7 support library that includes Material design styles .

From here I am little bit confused !
Suppose that my default theme extends from `Theme.AppCompat` .

Why Should I provide an alternative style for 21 api knowing that  `Theme.AppCompat` is made for compatibility ?

Comment: *so for this purpose we need to provide alternative styles that will work on devices running earlier version* where? the appcompat-v7 is evolving ... I'm sure that you no longer should do this ... even if then do something like `BaseTheme` extends `Theme.AppCompat` by default and `Theme.Material` for v21 ... then your `AppTheme` extends `BaseTheme`  ... and put customization to `AppTheme`

Comment: Who says you should? Don't, it'll work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do so to use functionalities from api 21 that does not previously exist.
For exemple, on api 21 and later you can make the statusbar translucent, and this is not done by default with the appcompat, because that's not the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In a general sense, AppCompat back ports everything that you will generally need to worry about (with new features added all the time). AppCompat itself is doing that alternative style heavy lifting for you.

Start with AppCompat and only create an alternative style if you run in to a specific feature that you need (you probably won't).